# Django Viewflow: Quick Start says to include formpack. What is a formpack?

Tags: django, django-forms, django-viewflow

I'm trying to use django viewflow to style some forms to keep a page consistently styled within an django app using materialize. In the viewflow documents, it recommends to include formpack javascript and styles into your database. What is a formpack and where could I find one for Materialize?

Comment: Could you point please, what document you've reading? To get started with Viewflow you can follow Quick Start documentation for full workflow - http://docs.viewflow.io/viewflow_quickstart.html or just CRUD http://docs.viewflow.io/material_frontend.html#quick-start